# javascript - parentheses regexp/parser

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following problem in javascript: I want to remove mismatched parentheses in a string so there is no nesting.

I have removed everything but `[^a-z\-()]` from the string.
Only `(` and `)` should be removed.
I think this describes what I want to happen.

1. If unopened `)` at the start then remove `)`
2. If unclosed `(` at the end then append `)` to the string
3. For each `(`, look ahead to the next `)` and remove all `(` before that
4. For each `)`, there should be no further `)` until the next `(` occurs.
5. Remove any `()` enclosing 0 or 1 characters, though this can be done separately.

So `a)b()(c)(de)f(g(h)i)j)(k` becomes `abc(de)f(gh)ijk`

`a(bc` becomes `a(bc)`

I also want to have only unique chars enclosed in brackets that remain, but again this can be done later

so `aa(bb` becomes `aa(bb)` then `aa(b)` then `aab`

Is regex the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to enforce rule #3 & #5 but the others although technically possible are just difficult.  The code should be easier to write as processing a stream of characters or iterating over the string as if it was an array of characters.  You just keep track of the state you are in...

Although regex is awesome it isn't always the best tool.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a Parser, for example:

```
function gets(s, depth) {
    var out = '';

    while (s.length) {
        var c = s.shift();
        if (c == '(') {
            var p = gets(s, depth + 1);
            if (!depth && p.length > 1)
                p = '(' + p + ')'
            out += p;
        } else if (c == ')') {
            if (depth)
                return out;
        } else {
            out += c
        }
    }
    return out;
}


str = "So a)b()(c)(de)f(g(h)i)j)(k"
result = gets(str.split(""), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, something like that would work. I guess this is what a regex engine does internally anyway. I can modify it myself if it fails any of my tests...